# Gnuplot plot two data with different time format

Tags: plot, gnuplot, time-format

I have two data with different time format:
file1 (%Y %j %H %M %S vel):

> 2011 170 0 0 0 0.017042
>   2011 170 0 30 0 0.002124
>   2011 170 1 0 0 0.061001
>   2011 170 1 30 0 0.096256
>   2011 170 2 0 0 0.073920
>   2011 170 2 30 0 0.048899
>   2011 170 3 0 0 0.039534
>   2011 170 3 30 0 0.044790
>   2011 170 4 0 0 0.052662
>   2011 170 4 30 0 0.063144
>   etc ...

file2 (%Y %m %d %H %M tide):

> 2011 06 19 00 00 2.1950
>   2011 06 19 00 05 2.2650
>   2011 06 19 00 10 2.3290
>   2011 06 19 00 15 2.4030
>   2011 06 19 00 20 2.4730
>   2011 06 19 00 25 2.5480
>   2011 06 19 00 30 2.6220
>   2011 06 19 00 35 2.6890
>   2011 06 19 00 40 2.7690
>   2011 06 19 00 45 2.8460
>   2011 06 19 00 50 2.8970
>   2011 06 19 00 55 2.9690
>   2011 06 19 01 00 3.0610
>   2011 06 19 01 05 3.1370
>   2011 06 19 01 10 3.2030
>   2011 06 19 01 15 3.2670
>   etc ...

Is it possible to plot those data within the same graph? If so, how to do it?

What I did is:

> set xdata time
>   set timefmt "%Y %j %H %M %S"
>   set xtics "2011 170 0 0 0",43200, "2011 172 0 0 0"
>   set xrange ["2011 170 0 0 0":"2011 172 0 0 0"]
>   set xtics format "%j"
>   plot "./file1" u 1:6 w lines ls 3 lc rgb "dark-red" notitle, \
>   "./file2" u 1:6 w lines ls 3 lc rgb "black" notitle axes x1y2

The result doesn't seem right.
Any helps will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must parse time of the second file manually. In gnuplot 5.0 this is very comfortable, because you can simply give `timecolumn` a time format as second option. Then it uses this format instead of the one given with `set timefmt`:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y %j %H %M %S"
set xtics "2011 170 0 0 0",43200, "2011 172 0 0 0"
set xrange ["2011 170 0 0 0":"2011 172 0 0 0"]
set xtics format "%j"
set y2tics
set ytics nomirror
plot "./file1.txt" u 1:6 w lines ls 3 lc rgb "dark-red" notitle, \
"./file2.txt" u (timecolumn(1, "%Y %m %d %H %M")):6 w lines ls 3 lc rgb "black" notitle axes x1y2
```

In earlier gnuplot versions you must first construct a string which contains all the time information and parse this string with `strptime`:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y %j %H %M %S"
set xtics "2011 170 0 0 0",43200, "2011 172 0 0 0"
set xrange ["2011 170 0 0 0":"2011 172 0 0 0"]
set xtics format "%j"
set y2tics
set ytics nomirror
mytimecolumn(c, fmt) = strptime(fmt, sprintf('%s %s %s %s %s', strcol(c), strcol(c+1), strcol(c+2), strcol(c+3), strcol(c+4)))
plot "./file1.txt" u 1:6 w lines ls 3 lc rgb "dark-red" notitle, \
"./file2.txt" u (mytimecolumn(1, "%Y %m %d %H %M")):6 w lines ls 3 lc rgb "black" notitle axes x1y2
```

Comment: Thanks Christoph, but the xrange doesn't work with file 2. Should I use x2range or how can I make xrange work for both data?  NB: I use earlier gnuplot

Comment: You set a fixed xrange, how should that be affected by file2? If you want autoscaling, remove the `set xrange` line. The autoscaling respects both data files, since the different time formats are important for the parsing only. After that, the time values are internally available as time stamps, and their original time format doesn't matter any more.